# How to uses insert or replace in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
 public function save($data, $id)
    {
      $this->db->insert OR REPLACE($this->table, $data);
      return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

if the data does no exist will be insert else the data exist will be replace

Comment: Did you called it as a static return since from a function, u need to make a self:: call

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CodeIgniter v3.0.x then all you need is  [$this->db->replace()](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#updating-data) as it compiles and executes a REPLACE statement. (MySQL documentation on [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html))

The trick is to include your table's key field (`$id` in your question) in the `$data` array. Then you only need to pass one param to `save()`.

```
 public function save($data)
  {
    $this->db->replace($this->table, $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
  }
```

I confess that I am not sure that `insert_id()` will return anything after `update()` is called.

Comment: This translates to REPLACE INTO, which (per the documention) works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. So you would get insert_id() just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> > Check ***Unique data filed to check where record exist***

```
public function save($data, $id)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = '{$data['id']}' ");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $count = count($result);

    if (empty($count)) {

        $this->db->insert('mytable', $data); 
    }
    elseif ($count == 1) {
        $this->db->where('id', $data['id']);
        $this->db->update('mytable', $data); 
    }
}
```

Comment: That's sending two queries from the script to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Shorthand:

```
$db_action = !(empty)$this->db->get_where($this->table, array('id', $id)) ? $this->db->insert($this->table, $data) : $this->db->where('id', $id)->update($this->table, $data);
```