# CodeIgniter Active Records Array index change in Insertion

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following php code to insert data to the table

```
$fields=$this->db->list_fields('branddistribution_products');
    foreach($data as $key=>$v){
        if(!in_array($key, $fields)){
            unset($data[$key]);
        }
    }

    $this->db->where('product_id', $data['product_id']);
    $this->db->from('branddistribution_products');
    $count = $this->db->count_all_results();
    if($count==0){
        $this->db->insert('branddistribution_products', $data);
    }else{
        $this->db->update('branddistribution_products', $data);
    }
```

and `$data` is an  array which have `picture 1` `picture 2` `picture 3`  key indexes.But when I insert to the db the key index change to `'picture' 1, 'picture' 2, 'picture' 3`.I have DB table column same as that indexes.The following database error arise

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1, `picture` 2, `picture` 3, `madein`, `Firme`, `heel`, `lenght`, `mainmaterial`' at line 1
```

How can I skip this index changes.

Comment: Not a solution for your issue, but you can smarten up your filtering step with: [array_diff_key()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) Do you _actually_ have spaces in your table column names?  ...a recipe for lots of future headaches.  Fix your column names, not your code.  I also recommend REPLACE INTO https://stackoverflow.com/a/34243189/2943403

Comment: Thank you @mickmackusa.I think so to change column name.